# Why does the accomulator is set to -10?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I would like to ask you, why does the accumulator is set to -10 in this case. I thought, that defaul value for accumulator is set to 0.

```
const number = [5, 10, 13, 18];
var x = number.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { return accumulator - currentValue});

console.log(x);
```

The output should be - 46, but is -36.

Comment: This is one of the reason I ([and](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) [others](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224)) prefer simple loops over calls to `reduce`. Unless you're doing functional programming with predefined, tested reducer functions, it's just far more complicated than needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't supply an initial value for the accumulator, the first call to your callback receives the first entry as the first argument and the second as the second. So the first call to yours is `5, 10` and returns `5 - 10` which is `-5`. Then the next call is `-5, 13` which is `-5 - 13` which is `-18`, and again with `-18, 18` which yields `-36`.

If you want to start with `0`, you need to specify that explicitly:

```
var x = number.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { return accumulator - currentValue}, 0);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

Live Example:

```js
const number = [5, 10, 13, 18];
var x = number.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { return accumulator - currentValue}, 0);

console.log(x);
```

It's also worth noting that if you don't supply an initial value for the accumulator, calling `reduce` on an empty array causes a runtime error:

```js
console.log([].reduce((sum, value) => value));
```